# Php extension not loaded

Tags: apache, module, php-extension, php

Using a  .user.ini file with `extension=geoip.so` (or mysqli.so) I'm trying unsuccessfully to load the relevant module: in the phpinfo() page of Php 7.1 (or even Php5.4) the module is never shown.

1) The .user.ini file is working correctly because I'm able to modify the variable memory_limit.

2) The phpinfo() function correctly shows the extension_dir folder containing .so extensions that I want to load (in the php.ini file this variable is not present, however).

3) The php error log contains no message.

Every suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The `.user.ini` files can only set [certain PHP ini settings](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php). It just so happens that the `extension` setting is not one of them. In fact, [according to the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php), the `extension` setting is only valid in the core `php.ini` file. So put the `extension=geoip.so` in your main `php.ini` file.

**As a side note**: I use Ubuntu/Debian for most of what I do with PHP. The standard PHP distro that is available through the Debian package archives has extra code compiled into it that allows for a distributed configuration. The way this works is the SAPI module scans a `conf.d` directory and includes any `ini` files. Typically when you package an external PHP extension for Debian (which I might add is a pain - I've done it for my own extensions) you include a little `ini` file that includes the extension (e.g. `extension=myext.so`). The package installs it in the distributed config directory and it is included into the `php.ini` file when PHP spins up. Perhaps you meant to install a Debian-based config like this?

**Another side note**: Since you are probably using a CGI SAPI and might want different sites to load different modules (exclusively), you could perhaps look into getting the Web server to point the CGI PHP at a different `php.ini` file. I'm just presuming you want to achieve something like this. However loading modules for certain directories using `.user.ini` files is just not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try disable or configure selinux. Check selinux audit log.